# Initialize new Managed-Bean property (Pojo) in faces-config

Tags: jsf, properties, new-operator, pojo, managed-bean

At the oracle JavaEE 6 documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnawq.html#bnawy it seems like an Instance of a Managed-Bean property is initialized using:

```
<value>New</value>
```

But this is not working for me.

I have two Pojo Objects A and B.

```
public class A
{
    private B b;
}

<managed-bean>
    <description>A session Bean</description>
    <managed-bean-name>a</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>package.A</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>b</property-name>
        <property-class>package.B</property-class>
        <value>New</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Of cause I can create a new managed Bean called b and initialize the property with

```
<value>#{b}</value>
```

but this would be much easier.

Something like:

```
<value>#{new package.B()}</value>
```

is not working.

Is there a way to initialize it like this?